# Is $B \perp\kern-5pt\perp C | A $ for the two graphical models?

Tags: conditional-probability, independence, graphical-model, conditional-independence

I would like to know whether $B \perp\kern-5pt\perp C | A $ in the following two graphical models and would like to know if my reasoning is correct:

[image]

For the left graphical model, which is a Belief Network, here's how I deduce it:

$P(B,C|A) \propto \sum_{D,E} P(B)P(A|B)P(C|A)P(D|B,C)P(E|D) = \underbrace{P(B)P(A|B)}_{f(B)}\underbrace{P(C|A)}_{f(C)}$

Since the probability factors into a product of functions of $B$ and $C$, we can say that they **are independent** given $A$.

For the right graphical model, which is a Markov Network, I use the following method:

1. Remove all edges from $A$
2. Check if there is a path leading from $B$ to $C$

So we remove all edges from $A$ and we can see that we have a path, $B-D-C$ and hence $B$ and $C$ **are not independent** given $A$.

Is my reasoning correct? Also, for the Belief network deduction, is there a faster way to see this? My reasoning, without writing anything, would be to just say that since $A$ is not a collider for $B$ and $C$, then they are independent. Would this be correct reasoning?

Comment: For a related question about the same graphical model see [Is C ⊥ | A for the two graphical models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583373/is-c-perp-kern-5pt-perp-d-a-for-the-two-graphical-models)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments both for the BN and the MN are correct, provided those graphs are perfect maps for your two distributions (which are then necessarily different).

The formula-free explanation for the BN is correct, too, although I would add that the path $B\to D\leftarrow C$ is blocked because of $D$ being a collider.

Comment: Thank you. I just don't understand how is $A\rightarrow D \rightarrow C$ a path? It seems like in the BN it doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry, it is the path $B\to D \leftarrow C$ , I fixed it.

Comment: Hi Frank, do you mind taking a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583390/quick-way-to-determine-the-different-independence-assumptions) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583386/determining-unconditional-independence-in-markov-networks) Q's.